# What is a "commune" in Switzerland?

Tags: paperwork, switzerland

I have been asked for the following information:

> Si vous pourriez demander à la commune un certificat pour une explication de votre séjour en Suisse.

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=en&text=Si%20vous%20pourriez%20demander%20%C3%A0%20la%20commune%20un%20certificat%20pour%20une%20explication%20de%20votre%20s%C3%A9jour%20en%20Suisse.):

> If you could ask the municipality for a certificate for an explanation of your stay in Switzerland.

I'm not really sure what is being referred to as the "commune." Secondly, a certificate for an explanation of your stay in Switzerland doesn't sound like an actual thing.

I'm specifically asking about the municipality of Genève in Geneva, if that makes any difference.

Ideas?

Comment: Who or what is asking for this certificate?

Comment: A visa application center in Bern.

Comment: Commune is just French for municipality - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipalities_of_Switzerland

Comment: @NeilTarrant Sure but "asking the municipality," doesn't really tell me anything. There must be a certain office for this sort of thing?

Comment: For Geneva, I suspect you want the [OCPM](https://www.ge.ch/organisation/office-cantonal-population-migrations-ocpm). Be forewarned, everything with OCPM must be done in person, and you will have to queue for a long time to speak to anyone.

Comment: @Mo. What country are you applying for a visa for? Some countries only allow you to apply for a visa form the embassy/consulate/application center that serves your place of residence. What is your citizenship? What is you status in Switzerland? Are you a resident? In that case you should have a “permis”, and that’s probably what they are asking for.

Comment: @jcaron The problem is that residence permits have been backlogged up the wazoo due to covid. I have applied for one but I have not received it. The visa application center is claiming that if I can get the certificate they mentioned above then I won't need to return to my country of origin to apply for a visa.

Comment: @Mo. What they probably want is the residence permit, or alternatively something from them that either explains that there are these long delays, or some certificate that you have applied and the application is pending. Basically anything which explains that you are actually resident and actually authorised to be. In both cases, I suppose you would get that from the place you applied for the residence permit at.

Comment: @MJeffryes that sounds like an answer

Comment: (I'm a native French speaker but not familiar with Swiss administration.) This sentence was not written by a fluent French speaker. The grammar is wrong and “explication” doesn't make any more sense than “explanation” does in English. So you either need to guess what they're asking for and take a chance, or ask them to clarify, possibly in another language. The guess that they want an attestation from OCPM sounds plausible to me though.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Ha. Their English might be just as bad. This was the original English sentence: `Please get a proof paper from the community, then we can justify your situation and your trip in Switzerland.` Whatever that means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Commune or Gemeinde in German is the basic administrative unit of Switzerland, usually corresponding to a city or village.

In many cantons, you would have registered your arrival in Switzerland and applied the residence permit at a communal office (e.g. contrôle des habitants, bureau des étrangers, office de la population).

However, in Geneva, due to its small size and the city-canton structure, arrivals are declared to the canton directly, at the Office cantonal de la population et des migrations (OCPM).

While your residence permit is being processed, the communal office, or in your case, the cantonal office, can issue a certificate to attest your status in Switzerland so you can apply for housing and open bank accounts etc.

In Geneva, you can apply online as described at https://www.ge.ch/obtenir-attestation-office-cantonal-population-migrations/comment-obtenir-attestation-ocpm. The certificate will be sent to your registered address (unless you have an e-service account already).

It will contain your address and attest to your legal stay or residence in Switzerland.

Comment: Is there an English page explaining the process for getting the attestation? Besides popping it into [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ge.ch%2Fobtenir-attestation-office-cantonal-population-migrations%2Fcomment-obtenir-attestation-ocpm)?

Comment: @Mo. I can't find an English page for the process, but the language is fairly simple and the built-in translator in Chrome produces alright results for me. It will only be a simple online form to fill out with your personal information.

Comment: One last question: do you think using the [contact form](https://www.ge.ch/en/contact-ocpm) will also work? I looked at the form for the [residence attestation](https://ge.ch/ocpdemandeattestation_public/formulaire/Controler?action=login&documentId=ocpdemandeattestation&mediaType=ji_html&ids=userData,draftData&portal=StandalonePortal), but I'm not sure what type of permit I will even be awarded. It's hard to get beyond the first question.

Comment: @Mo. I would think it would work as well. But you might experience some delays right now as the offices are understaffed and overloaded due to COVID.